# Passing pointers into another function in C

Tags: c, pointers, dereference

Say I have a variable

```
int * foo;
```

I pass this variable into

```
func(int *x)
{
  *x = bar;
}
```

However, this does not work. However, if I put a non-pointer (say change it to **int foo;**) and directly put the address in, this works.

Why doesn't my first case work?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you're not pointing at anything.

Comment: show us how you call `func()`

Comment: You have to show all the code. Supply an SSCCE.

Comment: *foo must point to some allocated memory.

Comment: if my I set my int * foo to NULL? does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By declaring int * foo you've only created a pointer. foo is not actually pointing at anything yet - it's uninitialised. You might even get a segmentation fault from code like that, as the pointer could point outside of program memory. If you do:

```
int * foo = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

You will have initialised the pointer, malloc allocates some memory from the heap of the size passed to it. You can also do:

```
int bar = 0;
int * foo = &bar;
```

Which will make foo a pointer to bar (& returns the address of the variable).

Answer (score 3):

Your code is doing exactly what you are telling it too.  However, `int *foo` does not allocate any storage.  The pointer is simply a handle to a memory address.  In this case, it is arbitrary and results in undefined behavior.  Try the following instead.

```
void func(int *x) {
   *x = 42;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int *foo;
    int  storage;

    foo = &storage;
    func(foo);
    printf("%d\n" storage);

    return 0;
}
```

`foo` is simply a pointer to `storage` which is allocated on the stack by the runtime.  You are just as well off using `foo(&storage)` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
int bar = 235; // any value you want

void func(int *x)
{
    *x = bar;
}

int main()
{
    int *foo;
    foo = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    func(foo);

    printf("%d", *foo);
    free(foo);

    return 0;
}
```